# Return all items at once from class to form using tuple c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tuples

I created class in which I do calculations. I send data from my windows form, do the calculation and return values again to my form using tuple with 3 values. I did that but returning only 1 item at a time. When it get to second item it goes again in the form and do the calculation again and so on until all items are successfully returned.
I give little example:

Class (CalculationClass)- tuple return values

```
public Tuple<double, double, double> FunctionName()
{ 
               //calculation
    }
        return Tuple.Create(variable1, variable2, variable3); 
    }
}
```

Now when I return in my form I did it like this:

```
private void btnCalculation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CalculationClass sendVariables = new CalculationClass(variable1, variable2, variable3);
     // some other code..
    variable1 = CalculationClass.FunctionName().Item1;
    variable2 = CalculationClass.FunctionName().Item2;
    variable3 = CalculationClass.FunctionName().Item3;
    }
```

How to return all items at once from another class and assign their values to another variables in windows form?

Comment: It depends if the control you want to "bind" these values to supports Tuple<T1, T2, T3> if it doesn't.. you need to create a control yourself that supports Tuples. There is no standard way to bind all items on a Tuple at once in one line. It might be there in C#7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save your function result *once* or it will call the function multiple times:

```
var result = CalculationClass.FunctionName(); 

variable1 = result.Item1;
variable2 = result.Item2;
variable3 = result.Item3;
```